# mongoimport tsv error - "invalid bson in object with unknown _id"

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I'm trying to import data to a mongodb collection using the mongoimport function.  the file containing the data I'm importing is saved as a `.tsv` file.  (It has to be a '`tsv`' file as it has unicode characters which are lost when I save to `.csv`).

I use the following command to import the data:

```
mongoimport --db millie_db --collection ref_datas --type tsv --headerline --file vowels.tsv
```

and get the following error:

> error inserting documents: Client Error: bad object in message: invalid bson in object with unknown _id
>   imported 0 documents

Can anyone advise how I can find out what the problem is?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the encoding of the input file. I converted to UTF-8 using notepad++ and saved and all is good.